# Birthday paradox: How to estimate the probability of two or more people in a group of 30 sharing a birthday?

Tags: r, probability, birthday-paradox

I might be overthinking this. I generated the output in R and 5 of my 10 samples were successful, so that's 50%. Given that, if I am to estimate the probability of two or more people in a group of 30 sharing a birthday, what is my total sample? Should I be using combinations?

Comment: I'd say you're underthinking it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

Comment: What do you mean by "total sample"?  Wouldn't that be your "group of 30"?

Answer (score 2):

How are you generating your birthdays? To generate 23 birthdays:

```
dates = sample(1:365, 23, replace = TRUE)
```

To see if 2 or more share the same birthday:

```
length(dates) != length(unique(dates)) # TRUE if there are duplicates
```

How often is the above TRUE?

```
dupe_count = 0
runs = 1000000
for (i in 1:runs) {
  dates = sample(1:365, 23, replace = TRUE)
  if (length(dates) != length(unique(dates))) {
    dupe_count = dupe_count + 1
  }
}
print(dupe_count / runs)

[1] 0.508158
```

This closely matches the theoretical value of 50.7% in the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Calculating_the_probability)

Comment: With the expression `round(runif(23, 1, 365))` you do not generate dates uniformly: the chances of $1$ or $365$ are only half the chances of any other numbers between them.  This error won't noticeably affect the answer in this particular example, but repeating it in other situations with smaller ranges of numbers could introduce serious errors that might be difficult to detect. Interestingly, a two-sided test of your result yields p=3.6%, intimating it might be wrong: it's a tiny bit too large.

Comment: @whuber Good catch. I replaced it with `sample(1:365, 23, replace = TRUE)`

Comment: p = 1-cumprod(seq(365,266,by=-1) / 365) plot(1:100,p,type='o') 
abline(h=0.5,col='red')

Answer (score 0):

Here is slightly simplified R code for finding the probability of at least one birthday match and the expected number of matches in a room with 23 randomly chosen people.

The number of matches is the total number of 'redundant' birthdays. So if A and B
share a birthday and C and D share a birthday, that is two matches. It is also
two matches if E, F, and G all share the same birthday. [At the end of the code `nr.mat > 0` is a logical vector with a million `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s; its `mean` is the proportion of its `TRUE`s.]

```
set.seed(1210)
m = 10^6;  n=23
nr.unq = replicate(m, length(unique(sample(1:365,n,rep=T))))
nr.mat = n - nr.unq
mean(nr.mat > 0)
[1] 0.507083      # aprx P(At Least 1 Match)
mean(nr.mat)
[1] 0.679527      # aprx E(Nr of Matches)
table(nr.mat)/m
nr.mat
       0        1        2        3        4        5        6        7 
0.492917 0.363493 0.118073 0.022461 0.002798 0.000237 0.000019 0.000002 

hist(nr.mat, prob=T, br=(-1:max(nr.mat))+.5, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

*Note:* Demonstration of simulating the first 'room' out of the million to be simulated.
Any such simulation requires code for performing the experiment
(picking 23 birthdays) and code for quantifying the result (counting
matches).

The 'sample' function samples a given number of objects (second
argument) from a population (first argument). Sampling is
without replacement by default. Because birthday matches are
possible we are sampling with replacement. so we need
the argument `rep=T` in order to activate sampling with replacement.

```
set.seed(1210)
b = sample(1:365, 23, rep=T)
b
 [1] 342 166 265  24  34 270  71 268 111 230 186 100
[13] 239 106 350  27 345 268  33 135  33  32 178
```

Notice that `33` appears twice:  one match. Also,`268` appears twice: a second match.  Function
`unique` removes the two 'redundant' values. When we know how to
choose birthdays and count matches for one 'room', we can easily
loop though many rooms.

```
unique(b)
 [1] 342 166 265  24  34 270  71 268 111 230 186 100
[13] 239 106 350  27 345  33 135  32 178
```

Function 'length` counts unique birthdays. There are 21.
So at the end $n - 21 = 23 - 21 = 2$ matches.

```
length(unique(b))
[1] 21
```

[This page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/431093/probability-that-any-two-people-have-the-same-birthday/431103#431103) has additional discussion about matching birthdays.