# Probability that any two people have the same birthday?

Tags: probability, birthday-paradox

In Blitzstein's *Introduction to Probability*, it is stated that the probability that any two people have the same birthday is 1/365. However, isn't this the conditional probability that the second person has the same birthday as the first person, given the birthday of the first person?

Couldn't I prove this by simply generalizing the formula that no  *n* people have the same birthday:

$\ P = 1 - (364 / 365)^n$

And simply call *n =* 2, so that I can interpret the probability of having at least 2 people with the same birthday as the probability that 2 people have the same birthday? This would not be 1/365.

Is my reasoning flawed?

Comment: This question leads into several others, including the famous [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) about the probability of at least one birthday match in a room with $n$ people. (If $n > 23,$ chances are better than 50:50.// In solving these problems, it is customary to assume (a) the people are chosen at random (not from a twin's convention or a meeting of the Sagittarian Society), (b) Feb 29 does not exist, (c) the remaining 365 days of the year are equally likely for birthdays. ...

Comment: ... As always with such simplifying assumptions one (1) hopes that they are true or (2) knows they're not true but hopes they are mathematically harmless.// In the US equal likelihood for the 365 days is false but almost harmless. // Probability 2 randomly chosen people have same birthday is $1/365.$ Choose first person at random, note birthday; choose 2nd person at random, there is 1 chance in 365 2nd birthday will match first.

Comment: Related:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/336676/11887

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, yes, there is flaw.  According to your purported formula, the probabilty of having two people with the same birthday, when you only have $n=1$ person, is:

$$P_1 = 1 - \Big( \frac{364}{365} \Big)^1 = 1 - \frac{364}{365}  = \frac{1}{365} \neq 0.$$

So, you are ascribing a non-zero probability to an impossible event.  Have a think about whether that is the correct formula, and what kind of change you might make to it.

Answer (score 7):

One way to find the probability of no birthday match in a room with $n=25$ people is shown in the Wikipedia link of my first Comment. Here is a slightly different way to write it:

$$P(\text{No Match}) = \frac{{}_{365}P_{25}}{365^{25}}
= \prod_{i=0}^{24}\left(1 - \frac{i}{365}\right) = 0.4313.$$

In R, this can be evaluated as follows. [In R, `0:24` is a list
of the integers from 0 through 24; similarly for other uses of `:`.]

```
prod((365:(365-24))/365)
[1] 0.4313003
prod(1 - (0:24)/365)
[1] 0.4313003
prod(365:341)/365^25
[1] 0.4313003
```

So $P(\text{At least one match}) = 1 - 0.4313 = 0.5687.$

You can use R to make the first figure in the Wikipedia article as shown below.
The green line shows that for 23 people or more the probability of at
least one birthday match exceeds $1/2.$

```
n = 1:60
p = numeric(60)
for (i in n) {
  q = prod(1 - (0:(i-1))/365)
  p[i] = 1 - q
  }

plot(n, p)
  lines(c(0,23,23), c(.5,.5,0), col="green2")
```

[image]

Some people are surprised that matches occur with such high probability.
Maybe they are thinking at it would take 366 people in a room to be
*sure* of a match. But the graph shows that probability does not
increase linearly with room size. So it is "nearly sure" (probability 0.9941) to get a
match in a room of only 60 people. And the probability of at least one
match is above 1/2 in a room of 23 people.

Here is a table of some of these 60 probabilities (truncated at 30):

```
cbind(n, p)
       n           p
 [1,]  1 0.000000000
 [2,]  2 0.002739726
 [3,]  3 0.008204166
 [4,]  4 0.016355912
 [5,]  5 0.027135574
 [6,]  6 0.040462484
 [7,]  7 0.056235703
 [8,]  8 0.074335292
 [9,]  9 0.094623834
[10,] 10 0.116948178
[11,] 11 0.141141378
[12,] 12 0.167024789
[13,] 13 0.194410275
[14,] 14 0.223102512
[15,] 15 0.252901320
[16,] 16 0.283604005
[17,] 17 0.315007665
[18,] 18 0.346911418
[19,] 19 0.379118526
[20,] 20 0.411438384
[21,] 21 0.443688335
[22,] 22 0.475695308
[23,] 23 0.507297234  # first to exceed 1/2
[24,] 24 0.538344258
[25,] 25 0.568699704
[26,] 26 0.598240820
[27,] 27 0.626859282
[28,] 28 0.654461472   
[29,] 29 0.680968537
[30,] 30 0.706316243
 ...
[60,] 60 0.994122661
```

*Notes:* I agree with @Ben (+1) that your equation doesn't work to get the probability of a match between
two randomly chosen people. however, suppose you're among the 25 people in a room,  then with probability $1 -\left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^{24} = 0.0637$ at least one other person in the room will match *your* birthday.

Thus, another wrong 'intuitive' approach to the main birthday problem
above is to confuse the probability someone will match *your* birthday
with the larger probability that *some two* (or more) people will  have matching birthdays. (Among 25 people there are ${25 \choose 2} = 300$ *pairs* of people who may have matching birthdays.)

Finally, [this Q&A](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/327601/birthday-paradox-how-to-estimate-the-probability-of-two-or-more-people-in-a-gro/327608#327608) shows a method of simulating the probability of a birthday match. With a slight modification, that method can also be used
to find the expected number of matches.

Answer (score 1):

> Couldn't I prove this by simply generalizing the formula that no  *n* people have the same birthday:
>
> $\ P = 1 - (364 / 365)^n$

This isn't the right formula for no *n* people with the same birthday. It should be like

$$P_{\text{all $n$ unique}} = \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{365-k}{365}$$

and for $n= 2$ you get

$$\begin{array}{}
P_{\text{$2$ not unique}} &=& 1-P_{\text{all $2$ unique}} \\
& = &1- \frac{365-0}{365}  \frac{365-1}{365}\\
& =& 1-\frac{364}{365}\\
& = &\frac{1}{365}
\end{array}$$

The way to think about the formula is to consider drawing a sequence of $n$ numbers from an urn with 365 with replacement. Each draw we consider whether the drawn number is unique, ie. whether it differs from previously drawn numbers.

- The first number has a probability of 365/365 to be unique.
- The second number has a 364/365 probability to be unique (because 1 number out of 365 is already drawn before and 364 potential unique ones are left)
- The third number has a 363/365 probability to be unique (because 2 numbers our of 365 are already drawn before and 363 potential unique ones are left)
- and so on.

Answer (score 0):

1. Each person can celebrate his or her birthday on any one of 365 days,
   there are a total of (365)^n possible outcomes.
2. If each outcome is equally likely, we see that the desired probability is (365)(364)(363)...(365 − n + 1)/(365)^n
3. So every pair of individuals has probability 365/(365)^2 = 1/365 of having the same birthday.
4. I referd it from A First Course In Probability by Sheldon Ross 9th edition page no.37.

Comment: How does that formula in the 2nd point work? I see a term 365-n+1 that would be 364 if we use n=2 and this doesn't return in the 3rd point.